# Save Instagram API subscription in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, instagram

I'm trying to save pictures with an specific tag from instagram to a database.
So far everything seems to be fine except the writing to the database part. subscription is alright, I got the confirm from instagram API site:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=XXXXX&client_id=XXXXXX

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":   [{"object":"tag","object_id":"hashtag","aspect":"media","callback_url":"http:\/\/MYDOMAIN.com\/instatag\/instatag\/callback.php","type":"subscription","id":"3848897"}]}
```

I used the tutorial in this site for the code I have: [Instagram real time photo update with php](http://www.mtrinitaria.com/mykhel/tutorial-instagram-real-time-photo-update-api-with-php)

changed some parts to reflect my settings but even though I can see the requests coming in, it's not writing anything to the database.

here is the code I have:

```
    <?php

require 'instagram.class.php';
require 'appdb.php';

// Initialize class for public requests
// EDIT YOUR CODES HERE
$instagram = new Instagram('hashtag');

$myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ALL = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." ".$myString."\r\n";
file_put_contents('./activity.log', $ALL, FILE_APPEND);

// this is how I get my next_min_id and this is just an example
// you can code your own script on how to get next_min_id
// EDIT YOUR CODES HERE
$min_id_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `global_option` WHERE `option_variable`='next_min_id'");
//file_put_contents('./activity.log', (string)$min_id_result, FILE_APPEND);

while ($option_row = mysql_fetch_array($min_id_result)) {
    $next_min_id = $option_row['option_value'];

}

// Get hashtag media
$tagMedia = $instagram->getTagMedia('HASHTAG', $next_min_id);

// Display results
// EDIT YOUR CODES HERE
$rows = array();
//var_dump($tagMedia->data)

foreach ((array)$tagMedia->data as $entry) {
    file_put_contents('./activity.log', $tagMedia->data , FILE_APPEND);

    if (empty($entry)) {

        $url = $entry->images->standard_resolution->url;
        $m_id = $entry->id;
        $c_time = $entry->created_time;
        $user = $entry->user->username;
        $filter = $entry->filter;
        $comments = $entry->comments->count;
        $caption = mysql_real_escape_string($entry->caption->text);
        $link = $entry->link;
        $low_res=$entry->images->low_resolution->url;
        $thumb=$entry->images->thumbnail->url;
        $lat = $entry->location->latitude;
        $long = $entry->location->longitude;
        $loc_id = $entry->location->id;
        $media_id = $entry->id;

        // this is how I check if the media_id is already existed in my table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `media_id`='$media_id'");

        // if result is 0, I am inserting new row
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO `photos` (source, media_id, std_res, thumbnail, caption, user_id, user_username, user_full_name, user_profile_pic, published) 
                    VALUES ('Instagram',  '{$entry->id}',  '{$entry->images->standard_resolution->url}', '{$entry->images->thumbnail->url}', '{$caption}', '{$entry->user->id}', '{$entry->user->username}', '{$entry->user->full_name}', '{$entry->user->profile_picture}', '1' )";
            mysql_query($sql);
            file_put_contents('./activity.log', $sql , FILE_APPEND);
            if (!mysql_query($sql)){
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        } else {

            //echo 'exist ' . $entry->id;
        }
    }
}
// SETTING THE next_min_id IN MY TABLE
$min_tag_id = $tagMedia->pagination->min_tag_id;


$sql2 = "UPDATE `global_option` SET `option_value`='{$min_tag_id}' WHERE `option_variable`='next_min_id'";
if (!mysql_query($sql2)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

//$challenge = $_GET["hub_challenge"];
//echo $challenge;
//exit(1);
?>
```

On the activity.log I have:

> October 15, 2013, 11:58 pm [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381903108, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:08 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381903733, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:12 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381903933, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:14 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381904061, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:25 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381904759, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:26 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381904776, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]
>   October 16, 2013, 12:29 am [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "hashtag", "time": 1381904973, "subscription_id": 3848897, "data": {}}]

I created a database with two tables (photos, global_option), with the required columns. the only thing that seems to be working on the database is this *"UPDATE `global_option` SET `option_value`='{$min_tag_id}' WHERE `option_variable`='next_min_id'";* that changes the value of option_value to '0'.

Comment: I just got that i'm missing the json_decode() for the posted data. I'm trying it out but so far no positive results...!

Comment: the json_decode() gives me the same as the ones in activity.log but var_dump() is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, now this solved the problem:

**json_encode($tagMedia);**

and

foreach (**(array)**$tagMedia->data as $entry)

Comment: Mark your answer as correct answer for this question, that will be helpful to others to find and follow.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu thank you, please vote the answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: I come across here answering similar question .